# Is it possible to switch Azure functions standard DI container for another?

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, dryioc

Currently I am using DI in azure functions the standard way

---

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
       /*Register dependencies*/
    }
}
```

(Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.FunctionsStartup)

---

Is it possible to switch to https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc container while still being able to use DI to resolve dependencies through constructor of azure functions? If so, how?

Comment: Ok. Very interested to hear the answer as well. I did not checked it lately but the AF host was using the code from the DryIoc as impl. detail...

Comment: Hey @Stepan U! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the implementation in DryIoc https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/src/DryIoc.AzureFunctions/DryIocAzureFunctions.cs

There is a preview package as well: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.AzureFunctions/1.0.0-preview-01

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my question is that it is possible. But it requires implementing custom IJobActivatorEx and IJobActivator. And then replace it in IServiceCollection.

```
hostBuilder.Services.Replace( ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IJobActivator), typeof(ScopedJobActivator)));
hostBuilder.Services.Replace( ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IJobActivatorEx), typeof(ScopedJobActivator)));
```

I found this implementation in Autofac container extension https://github.com/junalmeida/autofac-azurefunctions in class ConfigurationExtensions

Sadly, I don't yet have working implementation for DryIoc.